# How to make custom content type as product in ubercart drupal 7?

Tags: ubercart, commerce

I want to make custom content types as ubercart products in drupal 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to http://mysite.com/admin/store/products/classes
2. Enter the machine name of your content type in the 'Class ID' text field.
3. Enter a human-readable name for your new product class (and optional description)
4. Click save

Ubercart will now register the content type with the machine name that you added in the above steps as a product. Next time you add/edit content of that type you will see all of the Ubercart fields in the edit form.