# Course as a Product in Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I'm trying to understand how course connects to product in ubercart.

There is a module called Course Ubercart, and I'm trying to create my courses as ubercart products with no luck.

Here's the description of the module:

```
Course ubercart 7.x-1.0-beta3   Supports Course as an Ubercart product and restricts enrollment to paid courses.
Requires: Course (enabled), Chaos tools (enabled), Universally Unique ID (enabled), Views (enabled), Views Bulk Operations (enabled), Entity API (enabled), Rules (enabled), Entity tokens (enabled), Order (enabled), Product (enabled), Image (enabled), File (enabled), Field (enabled), Field SQL storage (enabled), Store (enabled)
```

How am I supposed to use this? I have tried creating new products, looking to see if there is anything in the course content type UI for it, and I see absolutely nothing.

Comment: is this of any help: https://drupal.org/node/2106647

Comment: Slightly. I'm trying to figure out what they mean by "make the course content type a product" - any further clarification?

Comment: i think this should answer your question of how to make content type as product : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29542/how-to-make-custom-content-type-as-product-in-ubercart-drupal-7

Comment: Yes, but does that work if the content type already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just  putting my comments in as answer...

https://drupal.org/node/2106647

[How to make custom content type as product in ubercart drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29542/how-to-make-custom-content-type-as-product-in-ubercart-drupal-7)

You have to create content type as product. Thanks